# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object – with Python/NLTK word_tokenize

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, nltk

I have a dataset with ~40 columns, and am using `.apply(word_tokenize)` on 5 of them like so: `df['token_column'] = df.column.apply(word_tokenize)`.

I'm getting a TypeError for only one of the columns, we'll call this problem_column

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Here's the full error (stripped df and column names, and pii), I'm new to Python and am still trying to figure out which parts of the error messages are relevant:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-51-22429aec3622> in <module>()
----> 1 df['token_column'] = df.problem_column.apply(word_tokenize)

C:\Users\egagne\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   2353             else:
   2354                 values = self.asobject
-> 2355                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   2356 
   2357         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas\_libs\src\inference.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer (pandas\_libs\lib.c:66440)()

C:\Users\egagne\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\__init__.py in word_tokenize(text, language, preserve_line)
    128     :type preserver_line: bool
    129     """
--> 130     sentences = [text] if preserve_line else sent_tokenize(text, language)
    131     return [token for sent in sentences
    132             for token in _treebank_word_tokenizer.tokenize(sent)]

C:\Users\egagne\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\__init__.py in sent_tokenize(text, language)
     95     """
     96     tokenizer = load('tokenizers/punkt/{0}.pickle'.format(language))
---> 97     return tokenizer.tokenize(text)
     98 
     99 # Standard word tokenizer.

C:\Users\egagne\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py in tokenize(self, text, realign_boundaries)
   1233         Given a text, returns a list of the sentences in that text.
   1234         """
-> 1235         return list(self.sentences_from_text(text, realign_boundaries))
   1236 
   1237     def debug_decisions(self, text):

C:\Users\egagne\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py in sentences_from_text(self, text, realign_boundaries)
   1281         follows the period.
   1282         """
-> 1283         return [text[s:e] for s, e in self.span_tokenize(text, realign_boundaries)]
   1284 
   1285     def _slices_from_text(self, text):

C:\Users\egagne\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py in span_tokenize(self, text, realign_boundaries)
   1272         if realign_boundaries:
   1273             slices = self._realign_boundaries(text, slices)
-> 1274         return [(sl.start, sl.stop) for sl in slices]
   1275 
   1276     def sentences_from_text(self, text, realign_boundaries=True):

C:\Users\egagne\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py in <listcomp>(.0)
   1272         if realign_boundaries:
   1273             slices = self._realign_boundaries(text, slices)
-> 1274         return [(sl.start, sl.stop) for sl in slices]
   1275 
   1276     def sentences_from_text(self, text, realign_boundaries=True):

C:\Users\egagne\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py in _realign_boundaries(self, text, slices)
   1312         """
   1313         realign = 0
-> 1314         for sl1, sl2 in _pair_iter(slices):
   1315             sl1 = slice(sl1.start + realign, sl1.stop)
   1316             if not sl2:

C:\Users\egagne\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py in _pair_iter(it)
    310     """
    311     it = iter(it)
--> 312     prev = next(it)
    313     for el in it:
    314         yield (prev, el)

C:\Users\egagne\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nltk\tokenize\punkt.py in _slices_from_text(self, text)
   1285     def _slices_from_text(self, text):
   1286         last_break = 0
-> 1287         for match in self._lang_vars.period_context_re().finditer(text):
   1288             context = match.group() + match.group('after_tok')
   1289             if self.text_contains_sentbreak(context):

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

The 5 columns are all character/string (as verified in SQL Server, SAS, and using `.select_dtypes(include=[object]))`.

For good measure I used `.to_string()` to make sure problem_column is really and truly not anything besides a string, but I continue to get the error.  If I process the columns separately good_column1-good_column4 continue to work and problem_column will still generate the error.

I've googled around and aside from stripping any numbers from the set (which I can't do, because those are meaningful) I haven't found any additional fixes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what got me the desired result.

```
def custom_tokenize(text):
    if not text:
        print('The text to be tokenized is a None type. Defaulting to blank string.')
        text = ''
    return word_tokenize(text)
df['tokenized_column'] = df.column.apply(custom_tokenize)
```

Answer (score 24):

The problem is that you have None (NA) types in your DF. Try this:

```
df['label'].dropna(inplace=True)
tokens = df['label'].apply(word_tokenize)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize as WordTokenizer

def word_tokenizer(data, col):
    token=[]
    for item in data[col]:
         token.append(WordTokenizer(item))

    return token

token = word_tokenizer(df, column)
df. insert(index, 'token_column', token)
```

Answer (score 2):

It might be showing an error because `word_tokenize()` only accept 1 string at a time. You can loop through the strings and then tokenize it.

For example:

```
text = "This is the first sentence. This is the second one. And this is the last one."
sentences = sent_tokenize(text)
words = [word_tokenize(sent) for sent in sentences]
print(words)
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though it is already answered. My approach to this problem was the following:

```
# check for NaN values and remove them (optional)
df["column_name"].dropna(inplace=True)

# convert the column to string
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].astype(str)

# apply the `word_tokenize()` function
tokens = df['column_name'].apply(word_tokenize)
```

Answer (score 0):

> I had the same issue earlier today. I tried df.dropna(),
> df.astype(str) then I realized I could simply cast whatever variable
> it is into a string.

***So You can also perform data type casting on your input text like this:***

```
def stemSentence(sentence): 
   token_words=word_tokenize(str(sentence)) #*this is the cast: str()*
   token_words 
   stem_sentence=[ ] 
   for word in token_words: 
         stem_sentence.append(porter.stem(word)) 
         stem_sentence.append(" ") 
         
   return "".join(stem_sentence)
```